# Whats is the best framework Protractor or Jasmine?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have a situation. The webpage that I am testing is developed using AngularJS and KnockoutJS.

Search for a hotel and other pages in the website are developed using Angularjs.**

The Booking of the hotel and payments are developed using knockoutjs.

I am aware that Jasmine framework is used to test Knockoutjs applications.
Can I Use Protractor framework in c# for both Angularjs and knockoutjs application?

Or is there any other e2e testing framework to test such webapplications?

Comment: Opinion based/off-topic but I'm curious...**WHY** both?????

Comment: Do you mean Angularjs and knockoutjs?

Answer (score 14):

Protractor is for E2E testing and Jasmine is to javascript code testing. So if you're requirement is to test UI based testing go with Protractor or else go with Jasmine for code testing.

You go through following for more information on Protractor and Jasmine

**Protractor**

➔ It is an open source and end-to-end test framework specially for AngularJS web applications.

➔ It was introduced during AngularJS 1.2 as a replacement of the existing e2e testing framework ‘Angular Scenario Runner’

➔ It was built by a team in Google on the top of WebDriverJS with existing technologies such as Selenium, Node.js

**Jasmine:**

Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code. It does not depend on any other JavaScript frameworks.

**Protractor VS Jasmine**:

➔ Protractor has been developed for UI based testing activity(e2e testing), whereas Jasmine is to test JavaScript Code

➔ To develop e2e test scripts with Protractor, it needs BDD framework(Jasmin or Cucumber or Mocha) together for structuring the test scripts, whereas to test java script code with Jasmine, it doesn't require any other frameworks together